# Hyperbolic groups from Dehn functions

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory, gromov-hyperbolic-spaces

Hyperbolic groups may be defined as finitely generated groups admitting a linear [Dehn function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehn_function). I wonder whether it is possible to prove most of the classifical properties of hyperbolic groups in this context, probably using [van Kampen diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Kampen_diagram). For instance, using this point of view:

> Is it possible to prove that a hyperbolic group cannot contain $\mathbb{Z}^2$?

---

> Is it possible to prove that the size of the finite subgroups of a hyperbolic group is bounded?

Comment: The answer to both questions is yes, by using the theorem that linearity of the Dehn function implies other formulations of hyperbolicity such as existence of $\delta \ge 0$ such that all geodesic triangles in the Cayley graph are $\delta$-thin. One can proceed from there, for example, to the classification of isometries, and from there one can deduce that the centralizer of every element contains a cyclic subgroup of finite index. Hence a hyperbolic group does not contain $\mathbb{Z}^2$. However, I am guessing that's not what you have in mind?

Comment: Indeed, I know the usual proofs of these two facts, and I would be interested in alternative proofs which do not use this formulation of thin triangles.

Comment: I don't know of any alternate proof like that. If you assumed in addition that your $\mathbb{Z}^2$ subgroup was undistorted in both metric and area then you can get a very short proof, but that's a very strong hypothesis, and the existence of examples of distorted subgroups of hyperbolic groups makes it an unreasonable hypothesis.

Comment: I thibk it is a little easier to prove that a linear Dehn function implies that geodesic bigons in the Cayley group are uniformly thin, than it is to prove this property for geodesic triangles,. That's enough to prove that the group is biautomatic, and then you can use the results in Gersten and Short's paper about rational subgroups of biautomatic groups to show that, if the group contained ${\mathbb Z}^2$, then it would contain a rational, and hence undistorted, subgroup ${\mathbb Z}^k$ for some $k \ge 2$, contradicting linear Dehn function.

Comment: I think it should not be too difficult to prove that, if the Cayley graph is hyperbolic, then the associated Dehn function is linear. Therefore, if we are able to prove that the bigons in the Cayley graph are uniformly thin, then it is sufficient to conclude thanks to a result of Papasoglu implying the hyperbolicity of the Cayley graph. But I do not know Gersten and Short's paper, so I will take a look.

Comment: Whatever, proving that a linear Dehn function implies the uniform thiness of the bigons seems to be interesting. The argument I have in mind is the following: suppose that there a sequence of bigons $(\alpha_n , \beta_n)$ such that there exists $x_n \in \alpha_n$ and $y_n \in \beta_n$ satisfying $d(x_n,y_n) \to + \infty$; let $D_n$ be a van Kampen diagram whose boundary is precisely this bigon. Now, take some vertices $p_n,q_n \in \alpha_n$ and $r_n,s_n \in \beta_n$, such that $x_n$ is between $p_n$ and $q_n$ along $\alpha_n$ and $y_n$ is between $r_n$ and $s_n$ along $\beta_n$...

Comment: ...We get a new diagram $D'_n$ bounded by the (combinatorial) geodesics $\alpha_n$, $\beta_n$, $[p_n,r_n]$ and $[q_n,s_n]$. Now, we want to say that, if the distances $d(p_n,q_n)$ and $d(r_n,s_n)$ are sufficiently large, then $D'_n$ contains *many cells*. However, we have to justify that the distance between the geodesics $[p_n,r_n]$ and $[q_n,s_n]$ cannot be too small. Is it reasonnable?

Comment: @LeeMosher: you probably have these examples in mind, but there are standard examples (e.g., in the polycyclic world) of undistorted subgroups with exponential Dehn function in groups of quadratic Dehn function. So I don't see a too immediate way to tackle undistorted subgroups of groups with linear Dehn function.

Comment: @YCor: When I first wrote that comment I left off the phrase "and area", but then realized that I needed to put that phrase in for the comment to have any sense to it; maybe it still doesn't have enough sense. What I intended that comment to be was a warning to be wary of any overly naive approach.

Comment: @Seirios: Although I'm still skeptical about whether what you ask is reasonable, let me point out another relevant Gersten/Short paper: "Small cancellation theory and automatic groups", Invent. Math. vol. 102. That paper has an appendix which uses van Kampen diagrams to prove directly that a linear isoperimetric inequality implies other definitions of Gromov hyperbolicity. Perhaps that proof can be co-opted to find a direct route to the properties you want, bypassing the route that goes through the theory of isometries of hyperbolic spaces.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, it sounds interesting.